# Issue with UITableView - updating table values

Tags: xcode, ios, uitableview

I am a newbie. I have written some code for `UITable` but I am unable to update table values after adding the values to the array. I'm using a `tableview` subclass. The code is as follows. Check the last function. Now how can I update my table values?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_phones count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

       HLPFoundPhones *p = (HLPFoundPhones *)[_phones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Found (%1.2f,%1.2f) on %@" ,[p loc].x, [p loc].y , [p foundDate]];
       cell.textLabel.text = [p name];
       cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;

       return cell;
}


- (void)insertNewObject
{
    HLPPhonesAdd *view = [[HLPPhonesAdd alloc]initWithNibName:@"HLPPhonesAdd" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
    [view release];

   }
- (void)updateTable:(CGPoint)loc name:(NSString *)_name{
    HLPFoundPhones *a = [[HLPFoundPhones alloc]initWithLoc:loc name:_name];
    [_phones addObject:a];
    [phones reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

in your updateTable Function..

```
- (void)updateTable:(CGPoint)loc name:(NSString *)_name{
    HLPFoundPhones *a = [[HLPFoundPhones alloc]initWithLoc:loc name:_name];
    [_phones addObject:a];

   //give your tableView object instead of yourTableView
   [yourTableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: no luck.. any other suggestion..
does reloadData work on some other predefined function..?
I have got only 3 functions of table in my file... as given above .. none other function.. so do i need another function for it..?

Comment: Hadi, do these things..First check whether cellForRowAtIndex is called after you call reloadData(put a breakpoint there and check)..Second in updateTable function ,check your tableView object has a valid address(try to NSLog the object..)

Comment: nah its not calling it back.. btw i m using a full view to show table so at first my tableView did not had a name it was general after it i named it now after ur suggestion and its not calling the table view also..

Comment: can i recall the table function somehow....?
that updates the rows through this function is there anyother way...

Comment: Hadi..when you write/edit question, after adding all code to question, select these codes and click {} button just on top of the edit dialog, which will format code..

Comment: where you declared variable phones?

Comment: Have you checked whether phones is not equal to nil..just put a breakpoint in updateTable and hover mouse over phones..or just NSLog phones

Answer (score 0):

check value of _phone count and use in function

```
- (void)updateTable:(CGPoint)loc name:(NSString *)_name
{
    HLPFoundPhones *a = [[HLPFoundPhones alloc]initWithLoc:loc name:_name];
    [_phones addObject:a];
    [table_name reloaddata];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the array `_phones` is allocated.

Then there will be problems if the `[tableview reloadData]` is called inside a thread.
So confirm the reloadData is called from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your cell identifier looks to be same for all cells, which may confuse iOS which cell needs to be dequeued. So, keep your cell identifiers unique, something like below :

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell-%d", indexPath.row];
```

then, after table view is first displayed, update your datasource and call:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```